# Checking the value of a Swift variable inside the completion block of the method that initializes it

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, objective-c-blocks

Take the creation of `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` in Objective-C:

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"] completionHandler:^(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (task.state == NSURLSessionTaskStateCompleted) {
        // Do things
    }
}];

[task resume];
```

I can access the very task I'm creating, `task`, within the completion block as well without issue.

However, in Swift, if I try the same thing:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "google.com")
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(URL, completionHandler: { location, response, error in
    if task.state == .Completed {
        // Do things
    }
}

task.resume()
```

I can an error that "variable is being used within its own initial value".

How do I circumvent this?

Comment: "I can access the very task I'm creating, task, within the completion block as well without issue." No you can't, not with that code. `task` should always be `nil` or garbage inside that block. Since `task` is not `__block`, the block will capture the value of `task` when the block is created, which is before the download task is assigned to it.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**
I realize now that I didn't read your code carefully. You are not passing the closure to an initializer, but to a method. What I originally wrote is still valid when passing a closure to an initializer, but not in your case.

Your problem is similar though.

You have a `task` variable, which is initialized with the return value of a function. You pass a closure to the function, and inside the closure you are referencing the `task` variable.

The compiler doesn't know when the closure is executed (at least I don't think it checks for that, it's a `downloadTaskWithURL()` internal implementation detail) - and it's possible that it is executed in the function body (as opposed to have it stored in a property and executed at a later time). If the closure is executed in the function body, then it would access to the `task` variable when it has not been assigned a value yet (because the function is still executing).

If there were a way to let the compiler know the closure is not executed in the function body, then it would be possible for the compiler to handle that case. But swift doesn't implement anything like that.

Conclusion: I appreciate the compiler throwing an error for that, because otherwise I'd expect a runtime exception - although maybe not in your specific case (because the closure is executed later).

**Original answer**

As you probably know, in swift `self` is unavailable until all class/struct properties have been properly initialized, and a base initializer has been called (for inherited classes)

You are passing the closure to the class initializer - the compiler can't determine when the closure will be executed, so the closure itself cannot contain any (direct or indirect) reference to `self`.

In your case, `task` is the variable being instantiated, so when you are using it in the closure, it's like you are using `self`. That's not allowed in swift, so you have that error.

The same doesn't happen in Objective C because there's no such constraint in initializers.

Note however that conceptually what you are doing doesn't look a good practice. You are reading properties of a class instance **before** it's been properly initialized. To determine the status of the call, you should rely on the parameters passed to the closure, which ideally should provide all info you need.

Comment: Wouldn't the completion block only fire after initialization though? Isn't there kind of a silent guarantee?

Comment: Ok answer updated. I hope that explains the reason for that error.

Comment: By the way the premise of the question is wrong because his Objective-C code does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your task.state  has not been initiazed yet whith some value. You are trying to read properties of a class instance before it's been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way I have been able to get around this is to declare the variable before the initializer and then access it inside the closure:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "google.com")
var task: NSURLSessionTask?
task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithURL(URL, completionHandler: { location, response, error in
    if task?.state == .Completed {
        // Do things
    }
}

task?.resume()
```